# Converting a custom spinner library from Java to use with Kotlin. Problems with Listener

Tags: android, xml, gradle, kotlin, android-spinner

I'm working on a small Android App. The app uses a couple Spinners. I want to be able to use the spinners, but I want the first option in the Spinner to be a hint and not selectable.

I've found a number of workarounds here on StackOverflow. But not exactly what I am looking for.

I found the following repo on Github: https://github.com/sadra/AwesomeSpinner

And it is exactly what I want to do. But, it is written in Java, whereas my app is written in Kotlin. I know they are supposed to work together, but I'm unable to get this to work. I'm pretty sure it's my inexperience that is the problem more so than the repo or a Kotlin v. Java thing.

This is my Spinner. It lives in a Fragment in it's onViewCreated().

```
//String array
val companyNames = resources.getStringArray(R.array.companyName_array)

var nameSpinner = binding.spinnerCustomerName

//Adapter for spinner
nameSpinner.adapter = ArrayAdapter(activity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, companyNames)

//item selected listener for spinner
nameSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
        TODO("not implemented yet")
    }

    override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
        selectedCompanyName = companyNames[p2]
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Spinner Item Selected --> $companyNames")
    }
}
```

The AwesomeSpinner docs say to declare like this:

```
AwesomeSpinner nameSpinner = (AwesomeSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_customerName);
```

In my app in Kotlin i'm doing:

```
var nameSpinner: AwesomeSpinner = binding.spinnerCustomerName as AwesomeSpinner
```

This is where my trouble starts. I cannot figure out how to get the Adapter and Listener setup correctly. I have tried every way I can think of, but I am missing something or doing something wrong.

Working on this and I cannot get the adapter right.

```
companyNamesAdapter.setAdapter(nameSpinner, 0)
```

The above is incorrect. `.setAdapter` remains a resolvable resource.`

This is the corrected and working code:

```
//String array
var nameSpinner: AwesomeSpinner = binding.spinnerCustomerName

//Adapter for spinner
var companyNamesAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(activity, 
R.array.companyname_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)

nameSpinner.setAdapter(companyNamesAdapter, 0)

//item selected listener for spinner
nameSpinner.setOnSpinnerItemClickListener(
    object:AwesomeSpinner.onSpinnerItemClickListener<String>() {

    nameSpinner.setOnSpinnerItemClickListener { position: Int, itemAtPosition ->
        selectedCompanyName = nameSpinner.selectedItem[position].toString()
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Spinner Item Selected --> $companyNamesAdapter and $itemAtPosition" )
    }
```

My XML is set up and looking OK. As are the dependencies and repositories in `Gradle`.

Comment: from a future point of view, if you can't figure out how to write in kotlin, just write all of that in java and convert that file to kotlin

Comment: I tried that. Not only in this problem but others. I've never really had a lot of success with that conversion.

Comment: Looks like you mixed up adapter and spinner: `companyNamesAdapter.setAdapter(nameSpinner, 0)`. It should be `nameSpinner.setAdapter(companyNamesAdapter, 0)`

Comment: Well.....Guess I have to delete this account and walk away in shame. :) I cannot believe this. I have seriously been banging my head on this for 2 days! 2 DAYS! Thanks, good eye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copied code from their manual and it works ok in Kotlin:

```
    val spinner = findViewById<AwesomeSpinner>(R.id.spinner)
    val categories = listOf("Automobile", "Ariplane")
    val categoriesAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories)
    spinner.setAdapter(categoriesAdapter)
    spinner.setOnSpinnerItemClickListener { position, itemAtPosition ->
        Toast.makeText(this, "Selected on $position with $itemAtPosition", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

Does it helps or I miss you problem?

UPD. Looks like you mixed up adapter and spinner: `companyNamesAdapter.setAdapter(nameSpinner, 0)`. It should be `nameSpinner.setAdapter(companyNamesAdapter, 0)`

Comment: You caught the error in your comment above. Not sure if marking this as solving it is correct. Wanna edit this to point out what you found?